# using VBA to interact with webpages

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer

I've found some code online to use VBA to interact with Webpages and have since tweaked it. I'm trying to auto login to a website, then pull some reports...

Here's the code I have so far..

```
Private Sub IE_Automation()
Dim i As Long
Dim IE As Object
Dim objElement As Object
Dim objCollection As Object

' Create InternetExplorer Object
Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

' You can uncomment Next line To see form results
IE.Visible = True

' Send the form data To URL As POST binary request
IE.Navigate "https://e-oscar-web.net/EntryController?trigger=Login"

' Statusbar
'Application.StatusBar = "www.e-Oscar.com is loading. Please wait..."

' Wait while IE loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now())
Loop

Set objCollection = IE.document.getElementsByTagName("input")

i = 0
While i < objCollection.Length
    If objCollection(i).ID = "companyId" Then

        ' Set text for search
        objCollection(i).Value = "compId"

    Else
        If objCollection(i).ID = "userId" Then
           objCollection(i).Value = "uId"
    Else
        If objCollection(i).ID = "password" Then
           objCollection(i).Value = "pwd"
    Else
        If objCollection(i).ID = "securityMsgAck1" Then
           objCollection(i).Value = True
    'Else
        'If objCollection(i).Type = "button" Then
           'objCollection(i).Value = True


            ' "Search" button is found
            Set objElement = objCollection(i)
                    End If
                End If
            End If
        End If
    'End If

    i = i + 1
Wend
objElement.Click    ' click button to search

' Wait while IE re-loading...
Do While IE.Busy
    Application.Wait DateAdd("s", 1, Now)
Loop

' Show IE
IE.Visible = True

' Clean up
Set IE = Nothing
Set objElement = Nothing
Set objCollection = Nothing

Application.StatusBar = ""
End Sub
```

This seems to be working fine. It pulls the webpage up, fills out the three input boxes, then appears to "check" the radio button that I've acknowledged the terms and agreements, but when I uncomment out

```
  'Else
    'If objCollection(i).Type = "button" Then
       'objCollection(i).Value = True
```

The webpage gives me an error:

> ◾LOGIN ERROR:  Security messages must be acknowledged by authorized
>   users to access e-OSCAR.  Please try again.

like the radio button wasn't click, however, I can clearly see it's clicked. I commented that piece out, then ran it, the webpage pulls up with all 3 input boxes filled out, and the radio button checked. When I click "Login" it throws the same error. So it must be with the radio button itself or the way I'm trying to "click" it, not the code that's actually clicking the button "Login"

Does anyone have any thoughts (or recommendations that may resolve this) on why this might be happening?
 - IE 11
 - Excel 2013

Comment: Looks like you are missing the hidden field `_securityMsgAck` just under the checkbox

Comment: @Bloafer I made an update and now receive an error, any ideas?

Comment: I cannot see the update you are talking about

Comment: They didn't update for some reason... but I believe I've resolved this.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40723237/webpage-automation-using-vba/40724455?noredirect=1#comment68679360_40724455